# ERROR: User does not have appropriate authorization level for file WORK.SASMACR.CATALOG

Tags: sas

Anyone seen this error before?

```
"ERROR: User does not have appropriate authorization level for file WORK.SASMACR.CATALOG"
```

Occasionally, our batch jobs stops with this error. I don't understand how a file in work should not be writeable?
Thanks,
Stig

Comment: Hi. Please whether the below discussion help https://communities.sas.com/message/40327 https://communities.sas.com/message/157032

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link! They talk about setting the correct permissions on the folder, which I have already checked. Afterall, the jobs run correctly 99% of the times. And since it is a file in WORK, no other SAS session should be holding it.

Comment: Hi are you getting any other warnings or errors while running the process??

Comment: Hi Stig. Are there any chances that some one has opened your current sas instance in the server and accessing the file you mentioned. may be admin/any automated programs etc,etc., Just a thought.

Comment: virus scanner locking the file, perhaps?

Comment: Can you provide additional information about your environment?  Windows/Unix?  SAS version? Where is the work folder located?  Local drive? Network drive?  Externally mounted location?  Does this happen at all hours of the day or is it always an overnight batch job?  Is it always the same batch job that this error occurs in or do multiple jobs have this issue?  To find the location of your work folder you can do this: `%put %sysfunc(pathname(work));`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The drive is a local SSD drive on a VMware ESX host. The ESX is hosting 4 virtual machines, all accessing the SSD (using it as SAS-work). The machines are Windows 2008 R2. The error can come at all times. The last test I did, had this error in 3 out of 1000 jobs. @DomPazz that could be right, I have asked the AV admin to set exclusion for sas7bcat files, and the enitire SAS work folder. Asparajith, The error comes during SAS initialization, before the SAS autoexec is run and before the preassigned libraries (from metadata) is assigned.

Comment: Also check the Windows Indexing Service.  Windows could be trying to index the file for search and has a momentary lock on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I disabled antivirus (Sophos) online scanning for the work folder and *.sas7bcat files the error seem to have gone away.

Comment: One of our users experienced a similar (random, did not occur again) instance in EG today:  ERROR: User does not have appropriate authorization level for file WORK.SASGOPT.CATALOG.
ERROR: The Graphics option library cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

According to this http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001328775.htm , macro catalogs are usually read-only, except while macros are being compiled or updated. Perhaps this answers the "why this file in work folder is not writable" part of your question.

Comment: Thank you @user26029. The error is generated under initialization, before autoexec is started. I am not sure why SAS need to write to (or create) this macro catalog

Comment: Stig, is it possible that the SAS 'work' folder on your local drive is assigned the same location for more than one virtual machine or instance of SAS? That would cause an occasional read/write conflict.

Comment: And I think SAS automatically creates the SASMACR macro catalog to store compiled macros for the session. This occurs at compilation stage, before execution. Are you using macros in your batch code?